# Where should PythonWin be located?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, installation, pythonwin

I have a question about PythonWin.  Does it come with the DVD when you install it or does it have to be installed manually separately from the ESRI DVD ?

On my computer at work, it does not come with it, but when I am doing some training on Python I had to install it manually separate from the DVD .

Does PythonWin have to be within the ArcGIS folder under the Start Menu? My computer shows it has Python 2.7 folder but has no Pythonwin.

Comment: This page may answer your question: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/105

Comment: PythonWin is a simple add-on for the regular Python installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If PythonWin is installed on your Windows machine, it will likely be located at the following path:

> C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin

If it is not installed on your machine, download it from the following location:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/

It is important to install the correct version of PythonWin that will work with Python 2.7, which is the version ArcGIS 10.x uses.  Therefore, you want to download the .exe labeled:

> pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe

As a side note, I would recommend using a different IDE than PythonWin, as I have found the application tends to "hang" while processing resulting in no active print messages.  The IDE I prefer is [PyScripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/), which has a better debugger, more options, and tend to hang less often.